# Navigation and Update record in mysql database with html form

Tags: php, javascript

I am new in php and I want to make navigation buttons Next, Previous, Top, Bottom in html form which retrieves data from mysql database in php. And I also want to edit, delete buttons on html form. Please help in this regards.

Comment: Do you have any basic knowledge about php + mysql + html + js?

Comment: Then at least provide html + php code, so someone can see that you made some effort, as otherwise people will downvote this question or simply close it.

Comment: You have to add far more details and get more specific what your actual problem is. Just asking "hey I want to implement something, please help!" is not going to work. This board is a place to ask _specific_ implementation questions.

Answer (score -2):

some sort of code could be found here:

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=381&lngWId=8